# Configure stack ghci prompt

Tags: haskell, read-eval-print-loop, ghci, haskell-stack, nixos

Is it possible to configure `stack ghci` similar to the way `ghci` is configured via the `~/.ghci` file?

Currently `stack ghci` does not pick up the settings in the `~/.ghci` file.

I'm looking into setting the prompt to be a lambda instead of the loaded modules:

```
:set prompt "\ESC[33m\STXλ> \ESC[m\STX"
```

**Update**

> [neo@nixos:~/HaskellLearning/IdeTest]$ stack ghci The following GHC
>   options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it:
>   -threaded Configuring GHCi with the following packages: IdeTest Using main module: 1. Package `IdeTest' component exe:IdeTest-exe with
>   main-is file: /home/neo/HaskellLearning/IdeTest/app/Main.hs GHCi,
>   version 8.2.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help Loaded GHCi
>   configuration from /home/neo/HaskellLearning/IdeTest/.ghci Loaded GHCi
>   configuration from /home/neo/.ghci [1 of 9] Compiling Ch13
>   ( /home/neo/HaskellLearning/IdeTest/src/Ch13.hs, interpreted ) [2 of
>   9] Compiling Ch15             (
>   /home/neo/HaskellLearning/IdeTest/src/Ch15.hs, interpreted ) [3 of 9]
>   Compiling Ch17             (
>   /home/neo/HaskellLearning/IdeTest/src/Ch17.hs, interpreted ) ... Ok, 9
>   modules loaded. Loaded GHCi configuration from
>   /run/user/1000/ghci31082/ghci-script
>   *Main Ch13 Ch15 Ch17 Functor HelloError Lib Phone SemigroupAndMonoid>

None of the other 2 configurations mentioned does anything regarding changing the prompt.

Comment: I only use `stack ghci` and it definitely picks up the settings in my `~/.ghci` file. Is there something non-standard about your set-up?

Comment: have you set your `~/.ghci` file writable by just yourself? At least that's what my `stack ghci` complained about.

Comment: I haven't changed the ~/.ghci permissions.
Does using NixOS count as non-standard about the set-up? :)
Still, if I just run ghci instead it will pick the settings.

Comment: (You should probably say what the permissions were before you didn't change them.)

Comment: `-rw-r--r--` and I am not getting any warning when running `stack ghci`. I'll update the question since it says it is using the settings but it is not applying them for some reason.

Comment: I believe this is a NixOS issue as my config from `~.ghci` is being picked up in a Debian based distro.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your config under:

```
~/.ghc/ghci.conf
```

Works for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I tried that and it has no effect. It doesn't even say it is being loaded. I think this might be a NixOS specific Stack bug.